How to filter distict (unique) values?
In humio's query language, I'm trying to find a way to list all of the distinct / unique values in a result, e.g. select(["kubernetes.namespace_name"]) returns many thousands of results depending on how many logs have been written, but only a few dozen values. I want to get all the distinct values
Tried variations on count(...) and a few other things, but not got the result I hoped

I looked at the documents and didn't find a straightforward feature for that.
https://library.humio.com/data-analysis/functions-select.html
We can work around this  by adding the following
| groupBy(["kubernetes.namespace_name]) |select(["kubernetes.namespace_name])


That works great for my username, thanks!

(I meant 'use-case' there, must have been caffeine deficient when I replied before)
